# DocIdRedir.aspx sometimes redirects to search results instead of document preview

Tags: search, forms-services, document-id

I have a site collection with Document ID service enabled, and then a Document Library with DocumentID Value column exposed in the default view. For ~80% documents when an user clicks on DocumentID it is being redirected to the document preview (browser InfoPath form), but for couple of documents it is being redirected to search results instead. This always happens to same documents (documents exist in document library, DocumentID is valid and you can preview them by clicking on document name).

Does anyone have a clue what might be the problem here?

Link sample:
 http://intranet/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=CUSTOMER-1-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time I've seen this happen I've had duplicate documents (usually with duplicate Document IDs). This was either caused by

- Actually having duplicate document IDs, seemingly caused by some defect in SharePoint
- Search not crawling the documents properly

This may not be the cause of your issue, especially if you only have a single result, but have a look.

Comment: So what was the answer? I'm having the same problem, and I don't have duplicate document IDs