# SharePoint 2010 Document ID Link Opens to Search Page

Tags: search, library, hyperlink, document

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DocIdRedir.aspx sometimes redirects to search results instead of document preview](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11016/docidredir-aspx-sometimes-redirects-to-search-results-instead-of-document-preview)

I have set up my document libraries (2 of them) to utilize the DocID attribute. I have then used the Redirect URL in many places. This way if the document filename changes it will not break the link.

Example of the link

```
http://intranet/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=DL-1-1
```

The problem is now when you click on the link it directly sends you to the search page. It shows the document as the result (as if you had search for the document) and the search field text box is filled out with the DocID value.

Example of the Search Box content

```
docid=DL-1-1
```

Is this an issue with SharePoint or do I have a setting that is incorrect or that needs to be changed. Any thoughts?

Comment: What file type is that actual document? docx, pdf, xlsx...?

Comment: Hmm, It seems to be all the document types, including pdf.

Comment: I am tempted to close as duplicate of [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11016) question. Could you check if the answer helps you and get back?

Comment: Alot of the managers on the site renamed everything. I was able to reset the index after all the renaming and while the search was indexing and some files weren't available the DocIdRedir worked and prompted to view the file. Once the search finished indexing the DocIdRedir redirected to the search results page. There must be a fix for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is interesting because I was recently trying to get this result in a specific case and I was not able to achieve it.

In the Documentation for the Document ID Service it says:

> ### Document ID Lookup Behavior
>
> SharePoint Server 2010 takes a two-part approach when the document ID
>   service looks up document IDs to provide the best balance of document
>   IDs that work immediately and those that work across broad scopes:
>
> Search. Find an item across any location that belongs to the current
>   search scope. Search generally performs better as a cross-list query.
>   However, search is only as reliable as its last index. Therefore, if
>   an item was added but has not yet been indexed by search, it does not
>   appear in search results. Additionally, if an item was moved since the
>   last time it was indexed by search, then the old (and now broken) URL
>   appears in search results.
>
> Lookup specific to the ID provider. When an item cannot be retrieved
>   by using search (for example, if it has not been indexed yet),
>   SharePoint Server 2010 calls back to the document ID provider and
>   allows it to use its own lookup logic. This enables providers who want
>   to use IDs that work before search indexing is run on the last items
>   to look them up. The provider determines whether to perform lookups in
>   this way and what the most effective logic is for doing so.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559302.aspx

Comment: We started seeing this behaviour in 2023 now. FIles htat were moved from one folder to other folders are launching in search box. After sometime, they start opening ok however few files , even after two days are still launching in search box result